# Is this a VNC Software Bug? Connecting with a port number, is not asked for a password

Tags: linux, suse

I have SuSE Linux Enterprise 11 sp 4 installation and I usually use `vnc` for remote sessions. I installed vnc server through zypper function on server and there is no additional configurations done on server.

I want to connect through a specific port number, which in my case is 8080
(`x.x.x.x:8080`). But the problem is that if I use a port `x.x.x.x:5901`, the `vnc` software takes me directly to a graphical login screen.

I don't want to upgrade to SuSE Linux 12.

Comment: This sounds like a configuration bug rather than a bug in `vnc`. You never say anything about how the VNC server is configure or even if it's your local server on a remote one.

Comment: This is not a problem with the client, but with the server. Security can not lie in the client.

Comment: Does 5901 take you to a login screen, or to a session that's already logged in? If it's already logged in, is it the same session as on the server console, or a separate one?

Comment: Thanks for the kind replies, @Kusalananda I have installed vnc server through zypper function on server and there is no additional configurations done on server. I am using VNC from my PC. You are right, Please tell me what additional configurations need to be done on server.

Comment: @roaima Thanks for the kind reply, Yes when i use this port number it takes me to a login screen on server which asks for password i.e server OS username and password. The session is separate one and each time i connect it asks for username and password.

Comment: So what's the problem with connecting to 5901 and logging in?

Comment: @roaima it's a kind of security risk, as with normal process, it's a two step authentication, while connecting through this port, only single authentication is needed i.e linux machine root password.